# list all tags by creation date on a given commit

Tags: git

I would like to retrieve the last (chronologicaly) tag put on a given commit. So far I did not succeed to do it, it seems all tags put on the same commit share the commit creation date.

Sample of what I did using `git tag --points-at  my_commit --sort=-creatordate`

Here is a pseudo sample of what I try to achieve in eg bash:

commands (for testing purpose):

```
sha=`git rev-parse --verify HEAD`
git tag test_a
git tag test_c
git tag test_b
git tag --points-at $sha --sort=-creatordate
```

result (seemingly alphabetical order):

```
test_a
test_b
test_c
```

What I expect: (creation order)

```
test_a
test_c
test_b
```

I would like to find a way to retrieve that test_b is the last tag put on the current commit

## Solution

solution provided below in the answers and added later to ease reading:
Using annotated tags instead of tags allows to retrieve their own "creation" date.
So this test case works:

```
git tag -a test_a -m " a test tag"
git tag -a test_c -m " a test tag"
git tag -a test_b -m " a test tag"
git tag --points-at $sha --sort=-creatordate
```

results:

```
test_a
test_c
test_b
```

Comment: When you run git tag with none of  the `-a`, `-u`, and `-s` flags, you get a lightweight tag. These do not exist as Git objects, and therefore have no properties beyond existing. It might be possible to do what you want with annotated tags, but I'm not sure, which is why this is a comment and not an answer....

Comment: Hello @TurePålsson. You are right. Using annotated tags works as expected!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Ture Pålsson's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63942794/list-all-tags-by-creation-date-on-a-given-commit#comment113071400_63942794) has one of the keys here: only *annotated tags* contain their own date-and-time-stamps.  This is almost certainly the problem (it is with your tests, at least).

Each commit has *two* date-and-time-stamps in it, one being the *author date* and the other being the *committer date*.  Often these two are identical.  They differ when the commit has been rebased or otherwise copied: now the author date is the original date, and the committer date contains the date at which this particular *commit* was created.  (The author and committer name and email address can differ as well; for instance, this is normal with emailed patches, where the author is the person who sent the email, and the committer is the person who used that email message to create the commit.)

An annotated tag has similar information, although there is only the one *tagger* rather than a separate author and committer.

The `git for-each-ref` command—and in sufficiently modern versions of Git, `git tag` as well—has `--sort` options, as you are using:

> ```
> ... --sort=-creatordate
> ```

As [the documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-ref) says:

> For commit and tag objects, the special `creatordate` and `creator` fields
> will correspond to the appropriate date or name-email-date tuple from
> the `committer` or `tagger` fields depending on the object type. These are
> intended for working on a mix of annotated and lightweight tags.

So it looks like you have some lightweight tags, that don't have their own tag-creation dates, and `-creatordate` is using the committer date fields from the tagged commits.  The only way you can get what you'd like is to make sure that the tags are annotated.

Comment: Hello. I just tried with annotated tags and it indeed works. Thanks a lot for your answer. I will update my question to clarify how to do it